# Installing Jenkins windows slave from https master

Tags: java, jenkins, jnlp

I am trying to install the slave on Windows from a linux master. When using the Java Web Start, I get an error that it can't load the resource `http://jenkinsserver:8080/jenkins/jnlpJars/remoting.jar`
This is because the jenkins server is using 8443. Is there a way to tell it to use the correct port?

When I try from command line:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkinsserver:8443/jenkins/computer/Slave-it-jenkins-p2/slave-agent.jnlp -secret xxxx
```

I get a message that it is unable to access the jarfile `slave.jar`  Is it possible to use Jenkins on https and install slaves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to execute the same over https , if you dont have the proper certificate then you can either download them from browser or you can also pass the argument --**noCertifcateCheck** to ignore the cert.

For the above issue via http can you please provide the detailed error stack that will help

Answer (score 0):

First, you can configure your Jenkins port at **Configure Jenkins** menu `http://your-jenkins-server/configure/`. Check out the *JENKINS URL* at **Jenkins Location**

I had no problem configurating my Windows Slave using JNLP + service start. Just make sure that your JNLP port is set and open. You can set that port @ **Jenkins Global Security** `http://your-jenkins-server/configureSecurity/`

I used the Jenkins documentation [Installing Jenkins as Service in Windows Slaves](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-InstallSlaveasaWindowsservice%28require.NET2.0framework%29) as a guide.